# How to always show the menu on a single horizontal line?

Tags: css, menu

I have a problem with the site [www.majorofficial.com](https://www.majorofficial.com/).
I should set it to always show in one horizontal line, while now on some screens it goes on two lines (for example on the 13 "Macbook Pro). I tried from the theme settings but I can't, do you have any suggestions?

Thank you all!

Comment: in the media screen decrease the `padding` and `letter-spacing`

Comment: can you please provide the css of the menu?